# Cómo hacer una subconsulta respecto a otra tabla relacionada laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo el modelo `Site` el cual tiene una relación con `Template`

Site.php

```
public function template()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Template::class);
}
```

en el modelo `template` tengo una columna llamada `type`, perteneciente a la tabla templates

quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer una subconsulta para omitir ciertos resultados

En la tabla `sites`, la única relación que tengo para llegar a la tabla `templates` es a través de `template_id`

quiero obtener cualquier `site` (por eso el first() al final) cuyo `template` sea de `type == 0`, además también el place (eso ya lo tengo funcionando correctamente)

hice esto pensando que funcionaría, pero me está mostrando datos erróneos

```
    $templateType = 0;
    $templates = Template::where('type', $templateType)->select('id')->get(); //aqui estoy obteniendo los IDs que me sirven para obtener los sitios luego con el wherein
     
    $sites = Site::with('template')
    ->with(['place' => function ($query) use ($placeId) {
        $query->where('id', '=', $placeId);
    }])->whereIn('template_id', $templates)->first();
```

Comment: ¿Nos muestras la relación que definiste en template?

Comment: Entonces, quieres el primer Site cuyo template sea de un cierto tipo y que además cumpla con un cierto $placeId, que me imagino pasas como parámetro de la ruta?

Comment: así es @ffflabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$sites = Site::with('template')
    ->with(['place' => function ($query) use ($placeId) {
        $query->where('id', '=', $placeId);
    }])
    ->whereHas('template', function ($query){ /* aqui le dices que quieres solo sites que tengan templates con type = 0 */
        $query->where('type',0);
    })
    ->first();
```

**EDIT**
Es bueno aclarar como comento @ffflabs que esta query puede llegar a traer un Site con template que tenga type = 0 pero que no tenga place.

Como la pregunta decía que esa parte ya estaba resuelta, no se le presto atención.

Para asegurarnos que sea un Site con un Template con type = 0 y además que tenga un place con ese $placeId, se puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$site = Site::with('template')
        ->with(['place' => function ($query) use ($placeId) {
            $query->where('id', '=', $placeId);
        }])
        ->whereHas('place', function ($query) use ($placeId){ /* aqui te aseguras que tenga el place con ese $placeId */
            $query->where('id', '=', $placeId);
        })
        ->whereHas('template', function ($query){ /* aqui le dices que quieres solo sites que tengan templates con type = 0 */
            $query->where('type',0);
        })
        ->first();
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Ojo: con esta consulta puede que el primer Site con template tipo 0 tenga un place distinto a `$placeId`. En ese caso el Site cumple, sólo que el place vendría vacío

Comment: gracias por la aclaración en el edit, sin embargo, en mi aplicación es imposible que el usuario cree un "site" sin haber un "place", ya que es obligatoria la asociación para crear un site. pero se agradece la aclaración!

Answer (score 1):

Dados

1. los modelos `Site`, `Template` y `Place`, en donde

- `Site belongsTo Template` mediante la relación `template`
- `Site belongsTo Place` mediante la relación `place`

2. Un tipo de Template `$type`
3. Un id de Place `$placeId`

Los sitios cuyo template es de tipo `$type` y cuyo place tiene id `$placeId`

```
$sitios = Site::whereHas('template', function($query) use ($type) {
    $query->where('type', '=', $type);
})->whereHas('site', function($query) use ($siteId) {
    $query->where('id','=', $siteId);
});
```

*(Y si a eso añado `->first()` me da el primer registro que cumpla.)*

Si te fijas, no estoy usando `with`. A menos que quieras usar la relación en el resultado, la existencia se comprueba con `whereHas`.

**Tip 1:** Eloquent tiene métodos mágicos que, mediante la convención `where[propiedad en camelCase]`, permiten expresar la consulta en forma más concisa cuando comparas una igualdad.

```
$sitios = Site::whereHas('template', function($query) use ($type) {
    $query->whereType($type);
})->whereHas('site', function($query) use ($siteId) {
    $query->whereId($siteId);
});
```

Como no dices el tipo de relación con `Place`, sólo me queda inferir que `Site belongsTo Place` porque si fuera `Site hasMany Place` la relación la hubieras bautizado `places`.

¿Cuál sería la diferencia?  Bueno, :

**Tip 2:** si un Site pertenece a un Place entonces el modelo tiene la llave foránea entre sus propiedades, y el segundo `whereHas` está de sobra.   Suponiendo que la llave está en `site_id`  Podemos usar

```
$sitio = Site::whereHas('template', function($query) use ($type) {
    $query->whereType($type);
})
->whereSiteId($siteId)
->first();
```

Si un sitio tiene varios Place este tip no es aplicable.

---

Si acaso vas a necesitar datos del template o del place además de comprobar existencia, efectivamente hay que usar `with`. En caso que ambas relaciones sean de tipo `belongsTo` no es necesario pasar una query para limitar los resultados, dado que un site que cumpla con el `whereHas` no puede apuntar más que a un Template y a un Site.

La forma final, en este caso, quedaría:

```
$sitio = Site::whereHas('template', function($query) use ($type) {
    $query->whereType($type);
 })
->whereSiteId($siteId)
->with(['template', 'site'])
->first();
```